Cornell style notes formatting
I am a beginner so I apologize if this is a bad question. I am trying to write a latex document that has a similar style as the following image

So far I came up with the following minimum working example using the marginnote package -
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% entry 1 
\reversemarginpar \marginnote{title 1} 
\lipsum[1]

\paragraph{ }

% entry 2 
\reversemarginpar \marginnote{title 2} 
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

This generates a document as follows -

How can I modify my code to make it as close as possible to the first image? I want to remove the indentation from the first line on the right-hand side and increase the space between the keyword and the text. Additionally, I feel there might be a better approach than using an empty paragraph to add space between the entries.
Thank you in advance!

Well, there would be the titlesec package. I think your titles can be sections titles: it is correct?
So, try something like that.
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[rightmargin]%
    {\reversemarginpar\bfseries\marginnote{#1}}%
    {\thesection}%
    {0pt}{}[]

I think the explicit option to the package is necessary to comply with your style. This option enables the specific value for the current section title, while if you don't use this option you don't have to specify where to put the value within the format.
With this answer, there isn't any indentation in the first line.
To increase the space between the keyword and the text, I think you should look for the geometry package.
I give you back the MWE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[rightmargin]%
    {\reversemarginpar\bfseries\marginnote{#1}}%
    {\thesection}%
    {0pt}{}[]

\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\lipsum[1-9]

\section{My section}
\lipsum[10-12]
\end{document}

